# Advanced JPA Mapping with Compound keys - OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, mapping, composite-key, one-to-many, compound-key

I am using JPA 1.0 and have following tables, namely,  Type, Guide and Address (names simplified for clarity and highlighted in bold) It is a scenario, where in relationships between 3 tables is built on compound keys. Non key fields for every table are below the solid line.

**Relationships**

**Type**       One --------> Many                        **Guide**
**Guide**    Many <---------- One                       **Address**

**Type**

Code  PK
Date1 PK

---

Name

**Guide**
Code FK
       Date1 FK

Addr Identifier FK

Date2 FK

---

Value

**Address**

Addr Identifier PK

Date2 PK

---

Postal Code

(Pardon the formatting issue above)
I would like to start with Type table and unsing the compound key Code and Date1, get multiple rows (as a list) from Guide table.   Then using Addr Identifier and Date2 from the row I want to get a single row in Address table. Please note these are reference tables and the data does not change, so there are no deletes or updates on any of these tables

I have tried this simple set of annotations that are returning empty list. (code is implified for clarity)

1)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Type")
public Class Type
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "type", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Guide> listGuide;

    getListGuide() {
        return listGuide;
    }
```

2)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Guide")
public Class Guide

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "Code"),
         @JoinColumn(name = "Date1") })
private Type type;
```

When I use getListGuide() I am getting an empty list.

Can you please suggest a solution?

I also need a mapping solution between Guide and Address entities.

Regards,

Comment: @JB Nizet I don;t know how static slipped in there, when it did not belong there :-)

Comment: @JB Nizet I am thinking on the same lines of a join table, but if you notice the table Guide has a state by way of a field called Value.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use JPA 1 in stead of JPA 2?